# Change Resource Type property in asp.net mvc-5

Tags: c#, assembly, properties, asp.net-mvc-5, embedded-resource

Is there any way to change the `Build-Action` of a resource in C#. I have done it manually on the local-system but when published this project on `TFS-Domain`, it does not load the file and gives an exception:

```
{"No resource with name myAppName.Assets.fonts.abc.ttf"}
```

The point is I don't want to do it manually always when I publish the site (manual-steps are):

1. Right-clicked on the file
2. Clicked on Properties
3. Changed its Build-Action from `Content` to `Embedded Resource`

Comment: How do you access it? Embedded resource becomes part of your assembly so you access it a little differently.

Comment: Yes, i have accessed it using **Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(Path+FileName)** as a Stream object

Comment: Does the file change,  or is it generated by your code.  Reason I ask is because it should only ever need to be set to Embedded resource once.

Comment: It is only once added to the project by us(the developers). (Yes, i'll handle that ONCE-WORK in my code, but i want it in c#)

Comment: In your comment above does path refer to a physical disk path or a namespace?

Comment: It is like **Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("myAppName.Assets.fonts.abc.ttf")** while debugging. There is no problem with this line. (The thing i want is to embed the resource automatically in c#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy the files into your app_data directory and access is normally instead of making it a embedded resource.

`var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/abc.ttf");`